# Outlook does not support acymailing newsletter's image width and height

Tags: image, joomla, outlook-2007, newsletter

I am working on acymailing newsletter template. I am using module to insert dynamic properties.But when we are adding module content with  image about 600*300 with custom size i.e 121*78 .In gmail it is showing image with 121*78 px, but in outlook it is showing images with original size i.e 600*300 px. Which suffer my acymailing newsletter look and feel.I am building template in table format. And i have used all method to reduce size but in outlook it is taking original size.
Please provide the instruction to email image with custom size.

thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are setting it, but this will work in all clients including Outlook:

```
<img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="yourImage.jpg" width="121" height="78" alt="">
```